# javascript not working in android

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have a webview in my program. 
I loaded a string into this webview that contains javascript function. When i loaded it in the emulator it's not working
i.e if I write a simple alert the webView won't display the alert.
I have enabled the javascript. But then also its not working.
what may be the reason?
Please help
Thankyou

Comment: Post your code, then someone might be able to help you

Answer (score 2):

Alerts will not normally work in a WebView. You will need to write the code to do that yourself. You can easily do that by implementing your own version of WebChromeClient. In otherwords:

```
class ChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

... 
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new ChromeClient());
```

Another thing I would recommend is implementing the onConsoleMessage as well. This way you can just use "console.log" in your JavaScript and have it directed to Toast or the Android Log.